# Data Migration from M1 to M2

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data, code-migration

i want to migrate only Customer data not site and stores data  from M1 i am using Ubertheme migration tool ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the Ubertheme migration tool before, however, you should choose a reliable data migration tool or find Magento migration expert to help you. Because there are many differences in structures between those 2 versions of Magento so there might be some issues during the migration process.

You can easily choose what entities and additional options you want to migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

In case you need, you can consult this complete tutorial video about how to upgrade to Magento 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2yJLuU7Saw

Comment: Sure   Thanks for your response

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah, if it's useful, please upvote and accept as a solution. Thank you!